# MATLAB code to realize a random binary source that generates bit '1' and bit '0' with probability p and 1(-p) respectively

Tags: matlab, random, probability, bit

I used a function to assign the value of p as per my choice. Inside the function I used the inbuilt function randsrc() to get a matrix of desired order and to generate the index value with a user defined probability. For example, to get a matrix of order 1X10 and to generate 1 with a probability of 0.7, I used randsrc(1,10,[1 0;0.7 0.3]). The first output was alright as i got 7 1's and 3 0's but when i ran it a multiple times, the output was not the same as probability of generation of 1's was not as per my desire. Can you please point out why or suggest a better approach to solve the question?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try many trials?

E.g.

```
q = randsrc(1,1000,[1 0;0.7 0.3])
```

produced 1000 numbers and

```
hist(q)
```

produced graph like this

[image]

Looks good to me, ca 300 zeroes and 700 ones.

Comment: Thank you but the problem is that it works well for large ranges but when I try to obtain the same result using a smaller range, say 10, the solution doesn't hold good.

Comment: Also, to repeat my earlier dilemma, as I run it multiple number of times, the probability distribution changes.

Comment: @Arshiya well, to fix distribution, you could set RNG seed. Wrt, `the solution doesn't hold good` could you please post graph and statistics, how do you know what looks good and what isn't?